# Lambda to upload (.dcm)DICOM file into AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

So What I'm trying to do is that I have lambda in python takes, input as a base64 and convert that base64 into DICOM(.dcm) file. But I can't be able to upload DICOM(.dcm) file. My bucket is not public and enabled 'Block all public access'.

This is my function:

`s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket_name, file_path)`

Also tried put_file_object function but no luck

I want that when the lambda converted the base64 into .dcm(DICOM) file, it should be uploading to s3 bucket.

Comment: Does the lambda write any errors to CloudWatch? May we please see these errors?

Comment: Sorry to respond you late. It was an error of IAM permissions, when the lambda try to put object into the s3 bucket need to allow s3 bucket that when the request is coming from specific lambda it should allow it. And by handling IAM permissions, my issue was fixed.